# How to make R Markdown links with boxes like LaTeX documents?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, knitr

First, I have a .Rmd file using `knitr` to generate a pdf, it only contains a link:

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "my name"
date: "2020/2/6"
output: pdf_document
linkcolor: blue   
urlcolor: blue  
citecolor: blue  
---

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
```

and output is :

[image]

How can I change its pattern to default LaTeX style like:

[image]

Whatever it is a link, url or a cite, how to change it to LaTeX style with red or green boxes above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally these boxes are shown by default. Unfortunately rmarkdown disables them, but you can undo the the changes made by rmarkdown:

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "my name"
date: "2020/2/6"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
    - \hypersetup{colorlinks = false,pdfborder={1 1 1}}
---

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
```

Comment: Do you know how to [create citations to references with a hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087346/in-r-markdown-how-do-i-create-citations-to-references-with-a-hyperlink) ?