# In R Markdown, how do I create citations to references with a hyperlink?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Now I have a RMarkdown file, when the citation for the reference is clicked, I want the reader to be navigated to the corresponding reference in the bibliography.

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "my name"
date: "2020/2/6"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
    - \hypersetup{colorlinks = false,pdfborder={1 1 1}}


bibliography: bibfile.bib
---

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

This is my reference[@Breiman2001].
```

[image]

I want the effect could be like this:

[image]

this is the `.bib` file:

```
@article{Breiman2001,
  title={Random Forests},
  author={Breiman, Leo},
  journal={Machine Learning},
  volume={45},
  number={1},
  pages={5-32},
  year={2001},
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by adding `link-citations: true` in your YAML.

See this other question on SO for more details: [Rmarkdown removes citation hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233827/rmarkdown-removes-citation-hyperlink)